# Virsh corruption image, re-merge snapshot?

Tags: snapshot, restore, virsh

I have an issue with one of my images. The image is encrypted.

About three weeks ago I started a snapshot of a running image and then did a blockcommit more recently. Something has since happened to that image and it no longer boots. I can run "virsh start vm1" and it starts running, but if I connect to the console ("virsh console vm1") it never prompts for the key to unlock the disk. There are no errors in the logs.

Now, I have the back image file from a few weeks ago, however it is now outdate. I also still have now obsolete snapshot file that was committed.

Is it possible to somehow reload the outdated image re-apply the changes from the snapshot?